# while loop and getchar() - large input

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, line, getchar

The following code does not allow me to input anything above 4095 characters unless i type `\n`, and i would like to know why it occurs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    unsigned long long a = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        ++a;
    printf("\n%llu\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

E.g:

```
input: '#' * 4094

output: 4094

input: '#' * 4095 

output: 4095

input: '#' * 4096

output: 4095
```

and so on...

but if i type `\n`, i will be able to loop more 4095 characters and so on...

```
input: ('#' * 4096) + '\n' + '#'

output: 4097

input: ('#' * 99999) + '\n' + ('#' * 99999)

output: 8191
```

Comment: Different exchange, but you'll see why: [How to read over 4k input without new lines on a terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131105/how-to-read-over-4k-input-without-new-lines-on-a-terminal). Short version: it's a limitation of your terminal; not your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [this answer on another Stack Exchange site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131105/how-to-read-over-4k-input-without-new-lines-on-a-terminal) explains, what you're seeing here is a limitation of your operating system's keyboard input handling ("terminal driver").

If you put your data into a file, and run your program with input redirection, like this:

```
myprogram < input.txt
```

then you should be able to read and count truly arbitrarily long lines.

There are other ways to get around the terminal driver's line restrictions, as explained at [the other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131105/how-to-read-over-4k-input-without-new-lines-on-a-terminal).